# Как вызвать необходимый метод в Angular

Tags: typescript, angular, frontend

Я пишу фронтенд для pet проекта на Angular, но мало знаком с ним. Я получаю несколько json-ов, после чего кладу их в поля класса app.component, представляющие собой массивы доменных объектов. Данный процесс проходит хорошо, json-ы успешно кладутся в поля, это происходит в конструкторе. Однако затем я хочу спарсить json-ы по значению ключей в новый массив типа интерфейс ProductCard, описанный тут же в app.component для дальнейшего использования в компоненте product-card.component (я так уже делал с интерфейсом Icon и компонентом icon.component, однако там я не парсил значения из json, а вводил вручную, т.к. количество элементов было фиксированным (всего 3). Массив productCards я хочу заполнить по прописанному условию в методе fillProductCards, однако я не знаю, где я могу вызвать данный метод? Заполнение данного массива мне нужно заранее, вызов через html отрабатывает нормально, но мне нужно, чтобы массив заполнялся при нажатии на button или что-то в этом духе(при вызове в div метод вызвается миллион раз). Где можно вызвать данный метод? Код прилагаю.

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from "./domain/category";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Product} from "./domain/product";
import {Offer} from "./domain/offer";

export interface Icon {
  width: number
  height: number
  src: string
  alt: string
}

export interface ProductCard {
  productId: bigint
  offerId: bigint
  price: number
  priceOverride: number
  article: string
  productName: string
  imageUrl: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  maleCategory!: Category[];
  femaleCategory!: Category[];
  products: Product[] = [];
  offers: Offer[] = [];


  maleMenuShow: boolean = false;
  femaleMenuShow: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.http.get<Category[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/categories/MALE').subscribe(result => {
      this.maleCategory = result;
    });

    this.http.get<Category[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/categories/FEMALE').subscribe(result => {
      this.femaleCategory = result;
    });

    this.http.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/products').subscribe(result => {
      this.products = result;
      console.log(this.products)
    });

    this.http.get<Offer[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/offers').subscribe(result => {
      this.offers = result;
    });


  }


  showFemaleMenu() {
    this.femaleMenuShow = true;
    console.log('success')
  }

  hideFemaleMenu(): void {
    this.femaleMenuShow = false;
  }

  showMaleMenu() {
    this.maleMenuShow = true;
  }

  hideMaleMenu(): void {
    this.maleMenuShow = false;
  }

  getProductById(productId: bigint): Product {
    let currentProduct = new Product();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      if (this.products[i].id == productId) {
        currentProduct = this.products[i]
      }
    }
    return currentProduct;
  }

  makeBig(number: number) {
    return BigInt(number)
  }

  icons: Icon[] = [
    {width: 30, height: 30, src: 'assets/img/icons/search.png', alt: 'Поиск'},
    {width: 30, height: 30, src: 'assets/img/icons/user.png', alt: 'Личный кабинет'},
    {width: 30, height: 30, src: 'assets/img/icons/cart.png', alt: 'Корзина'}
  ]

  productCards: ProductCard[] = [];
  currentProductCard!: ProductCard;
  currentProduct: Product = new Product();



  fillProductCards() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.offers.length; i++) {
      this.currentProduct = this.getProductById(this.offers[i].productId);

      this.currentProductCard = {
        productId: this.currentProduct.id,
        offerId: this.offers[i].id,
        price: this.offers[i].price,
        priceOverride: this.offers[i].priceOverride,
        article: this.currentProduct.article,
        productName: this.currentProduct.productName,
        imageUrl: this.currentProduct.imageUrl
      }
      this.productCards.push(this.currentProductCard)
    }
  }
}
```

icon.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Icon} from "../../app.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-icon',
  templateUrl: './icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./icon.component.scss']
})
export class IconComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() icon!: Icon
  @Input() index!: number

  width!: number
  height!: number
  src!: string
  alt!: string
  opacity: number = 0.5

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

product-card.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ProductCard} from "../../app.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.scss']
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() productCard!: ProductCard
  @Input() index!: number

  productId!: bigint
  offerId!: bigint
  price!: number
  priceOverride!: number
  article!: string
  productName!: string
  imageUrl!: string

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой подход, который вы хотите реализовать не очень подходит для того, чтобы работать с ангуляром. Есть более простой и удобный способ. Использовать AsyncPipe и RxJs.

Также замечу, что получать данные в конструкторе не корректно, так как вы конструктор относится к классу в TypeScript и нужен для корректной инициализации класса. А получение данных нужно уже для работы самого приложения на Angular, соответственно вам надо перенести получение данных к подходящий life-hook компонента. Чаще всего это ngOnInit.

В шаблоне передаем Observable и [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). При такой комбинации все отписки и отписки будут автоматические, также обновление будет происходить при изменении productCard.

```
<app-product-card [productCard]="productCard$ | async"></app-product-card>
```

В компоненте мы объявили productCard как Observable.
В NgOnInit получили данные, а дальше с помощью pipe и метода [.map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) преобразовали данные Product в ProductCard

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  productCards$: Observable<ProductCard[]> ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productCards$ = this.http.get < Product[] > ('http://localhost:8080/rest/products').pipe(map(products => this.fillProductCards(fillProductCards)));
  }

  fillProductCards(currentProducts: Product[]) {
    // Здесь логика на преобразование
    return //здесь нужно вернуть уже массив из ProductCard
  }
}
```